# Replace value of a line in a yml with bash

Tags: bash, shell, yaml

```
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
    - "35729:35729"
```

I would like to have a bash script to replace the `nginx` for an argument with bash script.

```
./script apache
```

Will replace `nginx` for `apache`

Comment: As it seems you want to override value in a docker-compose file, you might want to look at my docker [compose wrapper program](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.dcw) that allows default that can be overridden by environment variables (e..g to make the difference between a testing and production system). Because it supports YAML 1.2, it also relieves you of the need to quote those `"3030:3000"` port mappings that could be interpreted by compose's default YAML 1.1 parser as sexagesimals

Answer (score 21):

You can use this: `sed -r 's/^(\s*)(image\s*:\s*nginx\s*$)/\1image: apache/' file`

Sample run:

```
$ cat file
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
    - "35729:35729"
$ sed -r 's/^(\s*)(image\s*:\s*nginx\s*$)/\1image: apache/' file
web:
  image: apache
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
    - "35729:35729"
```

To persist the changes into the file you can use in-place option like this:

```
$ sed -ri 's/^(\s*)(image\s*:\s*nginx\s*$)/\1image: apache/' file
```

---

If you want it inside a script you can just put the `sed` command inside a script and execute it with `$1` in sustitution.

```
$ vim script.sh 
$ cat script.sh 
sed -ri 's/^(\s*)(image\s*:\s*nginx\s*$)/\1image: '"$1"'/' file
$ chmod 755 script.sh 
$ cat file 
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
    - "35729:35729"
$ ./script.sh apache
$ cat file 
web:
  image: apache
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
    - "35729:35729"
$
```

Answer (score 10):

You could create your script.sh as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 image value you want to replace
# $2 is the file you want to edit
sed -i "" "/^\([[:space:]]*image: \).*/s//\1$1/" $2
```

And then run:
./script.sh apache filename.yaml

Comment: Does empty quotes `""` are necessary? What they do?

Comment: Correct answer: `sed -i "/^\([[:space:]]*image: \).*/s//\1$1/" $2` , Remove the empty quotes otherwise it will complain about the no file or directory error !

Comment: to make it work both in Linux and OSX, add `.bak` next to `-i` e.g. `sed if.bak ...`. Then of course you can delete .bak file.

Answer (score 7):

since this is apparently a docker-compose file, you might want to try

```
 image: ${webserver_image}
```

and then set:

```
 webserver_image=[nginx | apache]
```

before launching. i believe this should give you a nice interpolation.

Answer (score 6):

**script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i.bak "s/\bnginx\b/$1/g" file
# \b matches for word boundary
# -i changes the file in-place
# -i.bak produces a backup with .bak extension
```

Now you can do `./script apache` to replace *nginx* with *apache*.